# How many users are there on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, users

I'm just curious: how many users are there on Stack Overflow altogether?

Comment: 240,975 users thats massive :))) well done stackoverflow

Comment: why is this a bad question? its honest and clear

Comment: after running a subquestion on my own- It seems that the last answer is the only right one since it balances out the deleted users and is constantly being updated - rather than the answer you adopted which is the least accurate!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can find this and more information at the [StackExchange site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

As of a few moments ago, StackOverflow boasts:

- 21 million questions
- 31 million answers on 70% of the questions
- **14 million users**
- 10 million visits per day

Comment: I think this number is exclusive *inactive* users. The total is then about: 455K users, 345K active, 241K registered.

Comment: @Balus -- Yeah, so? :) Besides, what keeps a user that has been [deleted for inactivity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/) to then reregister? What about merged users? What about spammers' sockpuppets?

Comment: You need to read "users" as "accounts".

Comment: how did you reach these numbers about the non active users?

Comment: New amount of users: 2,015,270

Comment: Active users' definition is different for each product, in general, it is anyone who gets some value from the website/app they visited/opened. It could be time spent or specific events triggered.
For instance, It might be a user who is doing at least one of the following :
1. Answering a question
2. Asking a question
3. Commenting, 
4. Searching/browsing questions/answers. 
5. Scrolling down more than 50% of the page
6. Spent x minutes on the page
... etc

Answer (score 11):

Go to the [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users) page, tab to the [Newest](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newest), peek the user ID of the latest user (it's in the URL if you peek/click the username link). Currently it's 454993. This includes registered, unregistered and inactive users. The Users page itself only shows registered users.

Comment: -1 that includes deleted accounts.

Comment: @George: that falls in the "inactive" category. Those users with some default lightgray face-avatar and without a profile page. Or do you have a different definition of it?

Comment: Regardless, deleted users are not users.

Comment: The method I outline in my answer gives a more accurate number.

Answer (score 5):

As of 22<sup>nd</sup> September 2010 there are 6885 pages of [users](https://stackoverflow.com/users) with 35 users per page.

Given that the last page won't be full there's between (6884 * 35) and (6885 * 35) **registered** users.

Answer (score 5):

The best way of finding this out is to use the API:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/stats?type=jsontext

According to the page, there are 344,686 users.

Comment: API v1.x is shutdown

Comment: data query: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/265871/200117

Comment: @Ciro it's not API

Comment: @ShadowWizard true

Answer (score 3):

**Data query**: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/227868/select-count-from-users

13M as of January 2021.