# How come the API and the user number count in the HTML code on SO don't match?

Tags: support, users, api

I am referring to this post:
[How many users are there on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65256/how-many-users-are-there-on-stack-overflow)

Why do the two solutions (API and HTML peek on newest user) seem to give incongruent numbers?

Comment: Incongruent how?

Comment: different numbers. one says around 1.6 million and the other states user 2 million something

Comment: I'm guessing a lot of users have been deleted.

Comment: The user ID is most likely simply a number that counts up and does not account for deleted/merged accounts.

Comment: Thanx to the clarifying comments : one is a static stampt (html) and the other is a running calculation which balances off the deleted users. therefore the answer to the linked question above is also the one given the least points since the rest will not be accurate by now.

Quoting George Edison: "The best way of finding this out is to use the API:

   http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/stats?type=jsontext"

Comment: Shouldn't it be a [tag:bug]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have termed the "HTML peek" method which is just looking at the user id of the latest user off the user roster sorted by creation time shows you the database user ID number. This is just an increment value. This means placeholders have been created for X number of accounts, it doesn't actually mean there are that many users now.

The API gives you a more useful number of actual current accounts.

I said "placeholder" earlier because often those are actually anonymous unregistered accounts that have not been bound to login credentials yet. It is not uncommon for folks to drift by and end up with several of these unregistered accounts before they discover that in order to maintain access to their account it makes more sense to register. At this point there is often a merge between any duplicate unregistered accounts.

But there are many other scenarios where an account may no longer exist. They may have been deleted for one reason or another.

To make a long story short, there is no discrepancy but you have to know *what the numbers mean*. An incrementing counter number on account creations != current number of users.

Answer (score 1):

The `/users` page doesn't display unregistered users, so even counting page numbers regardless of peek (which is off because of deletions and merges), there's still a difference vs. the API/SE.com counts.

Here are the current counts for Stack Overflow:

- Unregistered: 284,493
- Registered: 1,892,770
- Moderators: 43
- **Total**: 2,177,307